# Change the shape of button

Tags: ios7, xcode5

i don't know how to reshape the button. In xcode 5 button shape is rectangle initially.
But now i want to make it circle. 
I don't know how to implement this. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need an round button you can either set the type by programmatically

```
button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark];
```

OR

u can use Interface Builder

[image]

**Note:** If you need a custom round button then use a round image as the bachgrounf image of button 
i.e,

```
[button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple

just make an IBOutlet of your button and give that button corner radius as below

```
[btn.layer setCornerRadius:10.0];

[btn setClipsToBounds:YES]; //write this if you are using image in button
```

make sure that your button is square for perfect circle
and put half of the width as corner radius

**like if your button is of 100.0 width and 100.0 height then set cornerradius 50.0** `[btn.layer setCornerRadius:50.0];`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
self.yourButton.clipsToBounds = YES;
self.yourButton.layer.cornerRadius = self.yourButton.frame.size.width / 2;//half of the width
```

make sure that your button's width and height are same and type should be custom.

Comment: it add a image when i click on button... but i want to change the shape of button .. i want to show my button as circle.

Comment: remove the line yourButton.layer.borderColor=[UIColor redColor].CGColor;

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

1. Change the button `Type` property to `Custom`
2. Set a circular image to it.

Also, this is [another way to go](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-mask-an-image.html).

Comment: it works. but i want to know is there any other way to make a button circular.

Comment: Have you tried the link ? As well as the below solution for `setCornerRadius` ?